# Problema con envío de archivos adjuntos (.pdf) con PHPMailer. - PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, phpmailer, fpdf

Estoy intentando hacer un fomulario donde el cliente puede enviar un correo electrónico con un pdf que el elije desde su computadora. Sin embargo, cuando intento enviarlo o llega el pdf vacío o si lo hago de otra forma simplemento no se envía.

Así se muestra el formulario,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos son llamados desde la base de datos por lo que en el controller tengo una función llamada **DatosProfesorEmailController**.

```
function DatosProfesorEmailController(){
    $profesorData = DatosProfesorModel();
    
    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($profesorData)){
        echo 
        '
          <form class="mt-4 mt-md-0" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group not-empty">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtNombre" type="text" name="txtNombre" value="'. utf8_decode($item["NOMBRE_PROF"]) .'"  REQUIRED/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group not-empty">
                <label>Número de telefono del profesor</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtNumTel" type="text" name="txtNumTel" value="'. utf8_decode($item["NUM_TEL_PROF"]) .'" REQUIRED/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group not-empty">
                <label>Email del profesor</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtEmail" type="text" name="txtEmail" value="'. utf8_decode($item["EMAIL_PROF"]) .'" REQUIRED/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group not-empty">
                <label>Coloque el archivo que desea enviar</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="file" type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex">
                <input class="submit-btn" id="btnEnviarEmailDatos" type="submit" value="Enviar email" name="btnEnviarEmailDatos">
                <a class="submit-btn btn" id="btnRegresar" href="Contabilidad.php">Regresar</a>
            </div>
            
        
        ';
    } 
  }
```

Esa función la llamo en la vista y luego cree una función para enviar el email de esta forma.

```
function EnviarEmailProfesor(){
    if(!empty($_POST["btnEnviarEmailDatos"])){
        if(isset($_POST["txtEmail"])){

            $nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"];
            $numeroTel = $_POST["txtNumTel"];
            $email = $_POST["txtEmail"];
            $asunto = "Solicitud del informe para el torneo In Neh Kwan.";
            if(NotificarProfesor($email, $asunto, $cuerpo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])){
                echo '<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "success",
                        title: "Listo",
                        text: "Se ha enviado el correo electrónico correctamente a '.$nombre.'",
                    });
                        </script>';
            } else {
                echo '<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "error",
                        title: "Ops...",
                        text: "Ha ocurrido un error inesperado, por favor comuníquelo al equipo de soporte.",
                    });
                    </script>';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la funcion **NotificarProfesor**

```
function NotificarProfesor($email, $asunto, $cuerpo, $file, $path)
    {
        require '../mail/phpmailer/Exception.php';
        require '../mail/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
        require '../mail/phpmailer/SMTP.php';
    
        //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      //Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
   
            
            $mail->AddAttachment($path, $file);
           
    
            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
            $mail->Subject = $asunto;
            $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
            
            if($mail -> send()){
                return true;
            } else { 
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando envío el formulario me salen los siguientes errores,

```
**Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 659

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 659

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 659

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 659
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Could not access file:**
```

Así es como llamo ambas funciones en la vista,

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
     <?php DatosProfesorEmailController();?>
     <?php EnviarEmailProfesor();?>
     </form>
</div>
```

Por lo que al final no se envía el email y por supuesto no se añade el archivo .pdf. Es importante resaltar que el pdf lo he creado desde la misma aplicación con la libreria fpdf sin utilizar HTML, solo las variables de esa libreria.

```
    $academia = DatosAcademiaModel($id);
    $estudiantes = DatosRegistroEstuModel();


    $pdf = new PDF("P", "mm", "Letter");
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    //$pdf -> SetMargins(20,20,20); Margenes de la hora left,top,right
    $pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Total a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($academia)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 12);
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre de la academia: " . $item['NOMBRE_ACA'],0,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Monto total a pagar: " .$item['TOTAL_PAGAR_ACADEMIA'],0,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(10);
    }
    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    $pdf -> Cell(100,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(30,5,"Cedula",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(20,5,"Eventos",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(40,5,"Monto a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($estudiantes)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 9);
        $pdf -> Cell(100,5,$datos['NOMBRE_ATLETA'],1,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(30,5,$datos['CEDULA_ATLETA'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(20,5,$datos['EVENTOS'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(40,5,$datos['MONTO_A_PAGAR'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(5);
    }

    
    
    $pdf -> Output("Reporte.pdf", "D");
```

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_FILES);` y dinos qué muestra. Los archivos viajan en un array, porque el usuario podría **adjuntar uno o más archivos** desde un input de tipo file, si esperas un solo archivo adjunto puedes usar el índice `0`, es decir: **`$_FILES[0]['file']['tmp_name']`** y **`$_FILES[0]['file']['name']`**,  si esperas varios, debes sacarlos usando un bucle o algo por el estilo, esto último sería **lo más coherente** por lo dicho más arriba, a no ser que limites a 1 la cantidad de archivos a adjuntar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, donde lo deberia colocar, en la función de PHPmailer o bien en el controler que toma los datos de la vista? Podrías realizar una respuesta con el código de arriba para poder guiarme? Nunca he utilizado el var_dump, lo siento.

Comment: Intenté utilizarlo de dos formas, la primera así, 

if(NotificarProfesor($email, $asunto, $cuerpo, var_dump($_FILES[0]['file']['tmp_name']),var_dump($_FILES[0]['file']['name']))){
}

Pero me muestra el mismo error, 

Warning: Undefined array key 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 657

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Controller\AcademiaController.php on line 657

Comment: La segunda así, 

var_dump($_FILES);                         

            if(NotificarProfesor($email, $asunto, $cuerpo, $_FILES[0]['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES[0]['file']['name'])){
}

Pero me muestra el mismo error.

Comment: Si lograste solucionarlo, en la parte inferior, agrega tu respuesta, de este modo colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) y de paso te conviertes en el héroe de más usuarios que tienen el mismo escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Nooononono, acá no se edita el título. Por favor quien encontró la solución, publíquela como respuesta abajo en el campo titulado Tu Respuesta. Ahí podrá recibir votos positivos y marcarse como aceptada

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu nueva edición, donde dices que creas el PDF desde la misma aplicación ¿? En la pregunta original se interpretaba que el PDF era elegido por el usuario desde un `form`, mediante un input de tipo `file`. Entonces, ¿el PDF se genera en tiempo de ejecución o existe previamente y se elige del sistema de archivos mediante un form? aclara bien ese punto, porque si es el primer caso no necesitas usar la superglobal `$_FILES`

Comment: Perdon a todos por la tardanza, ya he dejado una respuesta clara de cómo lo realizé.

Answer (score 0):

Aclaro cual fue el método que utilicé para que funcionara el envío de correo electrónico.

Para empezar cree una nueva carpeta llamada **uploads**

Luego, en la pantalla de **Enviar reporte** le agregué una acción al formulario que apunta a otra vista llamada enviar.php de la siguiente forma. Aquí solamente se aceptan archivos en formato pdf pero se puede habilitar para imágenes y demás.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <?php DatosProfesorEmail();?>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mb-3 files color">
            <label> Seleccione: PDF  </label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="resume" accept=".pdf" required>
    
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="mb-3" align="center">
        <button name="submit" value="" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar informe</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

En la pantalla de acción cree una función para "limpiar" el tezto proveniente de los inputs llamada **clean_text** luege se valida que si se dá click al botón llamado **submit** entonces proceda a realizar el envío del corre, además el archivo se almacena en la carpeta **uploads** y se le envía a PHPmailer el path donde está ese archivo, porque al parecer PHPmailer solamente recibe una dirección para encontrar ese archivo y así enviarlo como adjunto.

```
function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}
$nombre = clean_text($_POST["txtNombre"]);
$email = clean_text($_POST["txtEmail"]);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $path = 'upload/' . $_FILES["resume"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $path);

    message = 'texto en html';
    
   
    require '../mail/phpmailer/Exception.php';
    require '../mail/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../mail/phpmailer/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                                           
    $mail->Host       = 'host del correo electrónico';                   
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
    $mail->Username   = 'correo electrónico al cual intento acceder';                 
    $mail->Password   = 'contraseña del corre electrónico';                           
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';            
    $mail->Port       = numero del puerto;   
    $mail->setFrom('desde cual cuenta lo quiero enviar', 'nombre de la cuenta');
    $mail->addAddress($email);      
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;   
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                            
    $mail->AddAttachment($path);                    
    $mail->Subject = 'Enviar informe';          
    $mail->Body = $message;                     
    if($mail->Send())                       
    {
        $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Informe enviado correctamente</div>';
        unlink($path);
    }
    else
    {
        $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Hubo un error al procesar envio</div>';
    }
}
```

En la misma pantalla de **enviar.php** se le puede agregar html para mostrar un mensaje de satisfacción.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reporte</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
                    <br />
                    <h4>Enviar informe</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Respuesta del sistema</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <?php echo $message; ?>
                        <a class="submit-btn btn" id="btnRegresar" href="Contabilidad.php">Regresar</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

En efecto se le pueden agregar más validaciones para que el tamaño del archivo sea el necesario, que se valide que en realidad sea un pdf y demás pero por el momento yo no lo necesito porque el reporte solamente lo envía la administración, aunque estaré trabajando en ello también.

En resumidas palabras básicamente se almacena el archivo pdf en una carpeta dentro del servidor y así de esa forma se le pasa como parametro al correo electrónico.